# Can't run a Spring Boot test for a simple controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a simple test:

```
package com.example.app;

import com.example.app.HomeController;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private HomeController controller;
    
}
```

and a Controller HomeController

The test lives in test/java/com/example/app
and the controller lives in java/com/example/app

Why can the import not be resolved?

It don't work without it either, which it what the tutorial suggests.

Without the import I still get the
[image: image of static typing error]

Edit:

```
.
├── [  96]  .mvn
│   └── [ 160]  wrapper
├── [ 128]  src
│   ├── [ 128]  main
│   └── [  96]  test
├── [1.9K]  .classpath
├── [ 395]  .gitignore
├── [ 835]  .project
├── [1.6K]  HELP.md
├── [9.8K]  mvnw
├── [6.5K]  mvnw.cmd
└── [1.6K]  pom.xml
```

I created the package from Visual Studio Code, but its just a simple maven init template.

Comment: 1) You test class does not contain any test methods. Show the whole code of the test class. 2) Explain what you mean by "can't run". How do you launch it - from Maven, Gradle, command line, IDE? What do you see when you try to run it?

Comment: There's no need import the controller if the test is in the same package.

Comment: please see updated description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test class contains no test methods. That's why nothing happens when you try to execute it.

What can you do? Implement at least one test method and annotate it with `@Test`.

Update:

The reason was a look up of a wrong name. No magical reasons. Everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: It won't run because I can't reference the controller its testing. Meaning it has no context

Comment: I get 'BUILD FAILURE' when running `mvn test`

Comment: @vuvgaG-dukgu3-wysnox: Show your project structure.

Comment: @vuvgaG-dukgu3-wysnox: 1) On the screenshot there is neither HomeController nor HomeControllerTest. 2) Show the source code of HomeController. 3) Run `mvn clean package` and show the results.

Comment: Compilation failure *** cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class HomeController [ERROR] location: class com.example.app.HomeControllerTest

Comment: @vuvgaG-dukgu3-wysnox: 1) On the screenshot there is neither HomeController nor HomeControllerTest. 2) Show the source code of HomeController.

Comment: @vuvgaG-dukgu3-wysnox: If it was helpful you can mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: You might want to update your answer to reflect that the issue was my naming of controllers, and the failure to import was due to it looking up the wrong name

Answer (score 1):

This is my example, I tried running and it worked -

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MainApplicationTest {
  
  @Autowired
  HomeController homeController;
  @Autowired
  OtherController otherController;

  @Test
  public void testContextLoading() throws Exception{
    assertThat(homeController).isNotNull();
    assertThat(otherController).isNotNull();
  }

}
```

Comment: Compilation failure *** cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class HomeController
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.app.HomeControllerTest

Comment: You don't need import statement if package is same. Try mvn clean compile. If you are using some IDE, create clean build. Also check if HomeController is in the package com.example.app. And it does not have any errors.